# How to play more than two songs using AVAudioPlayer

Tags: iphone

I want to play more than two song in my app. how do I can do it using AVAudioPlayer ?

Comment: Do you want to play them at the same time or at different times? What format are the songs in?

Comment: i want to play it one by one.when one song is finished then it will start another song automatically. And i am store all songs in one project directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to type up the answer, but google provides a perfectly good answer:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/27285-play-sequence-audio-files-avaudioplayer.html

The first piece of code from the page will just call all the sounds in sequence:

```
- (void)playSoundSequence { 

    // Make array containing audio file names 
    NSArray  *theSoundArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one",@"two",nil];

    int totalSoundsInQueue = [theSoundArray count];

    for (int i=0; i < totalSoundsInQueue; i) {

        NSString *sound = [theSoundArray objectAtIndex:i];

                // Wait until the audio player is not playing anything
        while(![audioPlayer isPlaying]){

            AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                                pathForResource:sound ofType:@"wav"]] error:NULL];
            self.audioPlayer = player;
            [player release];
            [audioPlayer setVolume:1.0f];
            [audioPlayer play];
            //Increment for loop counter & move onto next iteration
                        i++;      
        }
    }

}
```

But, you are probably better off using an AVAudioPlayerDelegate:

> If you don't want to wait in the loop, you can also make your
>   controller an AVAudioPlayerDelegate and implement

Code:

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
```

> This will be called when the end of the audio file is reached, at
>   which point you would start playing the next audio file.
>   audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying will then be called again when that one
>   finishes playing, and you start the next one after that, etc.